# Parallel RC Circuits For DC?

Tags: capacitor, resistors

Is there any use for parallel RC circuits in DC applications? Look at this now full diagram for example. The IC has 3 pins (mosfet maybe).

[image]
It seems that the resistor in parallel would only drain unnecessary current out of the source without changing anything on the output, not limiting current and not changing voltage.

Thanks.

Comment: Is there any use for a single capacitor in dc applications?

Comment: Can you sketch a schematic of what you have in mind? I find it a bit ambiguous, what's parallel to what?

Comment: All right I added a schematic :) I hope that it is clear now what I meant. I have a circuit that has a similar configuration on a pcb and I am wondering of what use the resistor could possibly be?

Comment: If that is all there is to it, then the whole circuit isn't making much sense from a practical point of view. There'll just flow a current through that resistor. I guess there must be more to it than that.

Comment: yes there is more but just a bunch of capacitors in series with C1 and also some in parallel would this make any difference sincee one can always go to an equivalent capacitance that looks like the one above

Comment: Keep in mind that not all capacitors work the same way. In real circuits (I'm thinking of filtering power supplies), capacitors have ESR (equivalent series resistance), so it's often a good idea to have a big capacitor for large amounts of charge in parallel with a little capacitor for fast response.

Comment: That's true, still without more of the schematic it's hard to tell the use of the resistor, it could provide a minimal load to the supply, as some topologies require a certain amount of current flowing to be able to regulate the output power, but that is just a guess.

Comment: Yeah, I have no idea what the resistor is. This could be an RC filter from my homework, or it could be a filtered supply with a load drawn in a funny spot, or...

Comment: I added the more of the circuit now and the parallel resistors value sais \$102\$ witch means \$ 10*10^2 \Omega\$

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes a (fairly large) resistor is placed in parallel to a capacitor to act as a bleeding resistor, i.e. to allow the capacitor to discharge quickly after the power is turned off.

This is a safety measure for circuits with high capacitance capacitors charged at high voltages (for example, high-power switching power supplies). Without the bleeding resistor the capacitor could retain a fairly large amount of energy at high voltage even after minutes (or hours) from power-off. Servicing such a circuit would be very dangerous, without the bleeding resistors, even when disconnected from mains, because it could deliver deadly electrical shocks to the operator inadvertently touching parts of the circuit.

Comment: the resistor value reads \$102\$ and its SMD so its \$1K\Omega\$

Answer (score 0):

Well a Capacitor is basically open circuit for DC. So here the capacitor will just be open circuit and will not affect the circuit. The circuit should essentially behave like a resistor in series with a battery.

However if initially the C is not charged, then it will be a short and a large current will flow through it for a short time.